# Aerospike - Read (with consistency level ALL) when one replica is down

Tags: aerospike

**TL;DR**
If a replica node goes down and new partition map is not available yet, will a read with consistency level = ALL fail?

**Example:**

**Given this Aerospike cluster setup:**

- 3 physical nodes: A, B, C
- Replicas = 2
- Read consistency level = ALL (reads consult both nodes holding the data)

**And this sequence of events:**

- A piece of data "DAT" is stored into two nodes, A and B
- Node B goes down. 
- Immediately after B goes down, a read request ("request 1") is performed with consistency ALL.
- After ~1 second, a new partition map is generated. The cluster is now aware that B is gone.
- "DAT" now becomes replicated at node C (to preserve replicas=2).
- Another read request ("request 2") is performed with consistency ALL.

It is reasonable to say "request 2" will succeed.

Will "request 1" succeed? Will it:
a) Succeed because two reads were attempted, even if one node was down?
b) Fail because one node was down, meaning only 1 copy of "DAT" was available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Request 1 and request 2 will succeed. The behavior of the consistency level policies are described here: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/understanding-consistency-level-overrides/711.

The gist for read/write consistency levels is that they only apply when there are multiple versions of a given partition within the cluster. If there is only one version of a given partition in the cluster then a read/write will only go to a single node regardless of the consistency level.

1. So given an Aerospike cluster of A,B,C where A is master and B is
   replica for partition 1.
2. Assume B fails and C is now replica for partition 1. Partition 1
   receives a write and the partition key is changed.
3. Now B is restarted and returns to the cluster. Partition 1 on B will
   now be different from A and C.
4. A read arrives with consistency all to node A for a key on Partition
   1 and there are now 2 versions of that partition in the cluster. We
   will read the record from nodes A and B and return the latest
   version (not fail the read).

Time lapse

1. Migrations are now complete, for partition 1, A is master, B is
   replica, and C no longer has the partition.
2. A read arrives with consistency all to node A. Since there is only
   one version of Partition 1, node A responds to the client without
   consulting node B.